# Parallax, not able to provide the same effect to all the pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i've basically tried to create a parallax effect using scrollmagic, and I was able to showcase it in one result but unable to do it on multiple pages, what am I supposed to do get the effect on all the pages.

So like I was able to do the code on one page but when I tried to do the same for the other pages, I was unable to do, when I copy pasted the same code for different pages with different classes, I didn't receive the same output as the first page, what should I do? Would be great if you could provide me with a structure of the code too as an example

Comment: I think what you should do is learning the basic. My policy is to never use code that I don't know what it's doing. It seems like you don't quite understand what your code is doing, hence you are copy/paste things around without any luck. What I would do is to fall back to the very basic and go from the core :)

Comment: I see, will work on it. Thanks!